# Increment views in Rails call also the model callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a dumb question.
To record views in my content I'm incrementing a value in my db with something like this:

```
@gallery.increment! :impressions_count
```

I have a lot of before_save callbacks in my model, and for every view I call also the callback. I don't want this, and I know that I can also call a `skip_callback` .

Is there a smarter way to keep track of impressions avoiding this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
Gallery.increment_counter(:impressions_count, @gallery.id)
```

I might also choose this way, update column is the standard way to avoid callbacks and updated_at changes.

```
@gallery.update_column(:impressions_count, impressions_count + 1)
```